# Proving A Sequence Is Eventually Constant

Tags: metric-spaces, solution-verification

> Let $x_n$ be a sequence in metric space $(M,d)$ s.t $x_n\to p$. Moreover there is $\varepsilon_0$ s.t for all $x_n\neq x_m$, $d(x_n,x_m)\geq \varepsilon_0$.
> Prove: $x_n$ is eventually constant

Let assume that $x_n$ is not eventually constant, therefore the elements of $x_n$ are not equal (exclude a finite number of equal elements).
Moreover there is $\varepsilon_0$ s.t for all $x_n\neq x_m$, $d(x_n,x_m)\geq \varepsilon_0$, this is true to infinite elements of the sequence so the sequence is not cauchy sequence therefore the sequence does not converges, which is a contradiction.

Is this proof valid?

Comment: You used the hypothesis of not being eventually constant when you said that the existence of a positive lower bound to the distance between distinct elements of the sequence implies that the sequence is not Cauchy.

Comment: To me, it doesn't seem like a valid proof. This part is somehow confusing: "... this is true to infinite elements of the sequence so the sequence is not Cauchy".
What exactly is true? For infinite values $x_n$, or for infinitely many $n$?

Comment: Hint for a proper elementary solution: $|x_n - x_m| \leq |x_n - p| + |x_m - p|$. So for $\epsilon: = \epsilon_0/3$, there exists....

Answer (score 2):

Your argument that if the sequence has infinitely many distinct terms, then the hypothesis ensures that it is not Cauchy and therefore cannot converge is correct. But you’ve not justified the assertion that if the sequence is not eventually constant, then its terms are all distinct from some point on, and you cannot: this is not true in general. What you should instead be trying to prove is that a **convergent** sequence that it not eventually constant must have infinitely many distinct terms. Convergence here is important, since the sequence $\langle (-1)^n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is not eventually constant but has only two distinct terms.